# A Java List as quick as like a Java Map?

Tags: java, performance, list, dictionary

I'd like to find a simplified Java Map, or List, where I do not care what the actual value at the values collection, but only care:

```
boolean containsKey(Object key): if the key exists
void remove(Object key): remove the entry of the key
```

On one hand, I'd like to save memory by using key set only (like a Java List), on the other hand, I'd to run above 2 methods in O(1) time. Order is also not in concern. So is this possible in Java? Thanks

Comment: Possibly an OrderedSet (or just Set if you don't care about order) is what you're looking for?

Comment: `HashSet` seems to be collection you are looking for.

Comment: @Taylor Yep, order does no matter. I'd like to google OrderedSet, never heard though

Comment: @Jun Then use a HashSet, as Jeroen explains below

Comment: @Jun `HashSet` uses `HashMap` internally it will take similar amount of memory, also both `contains` and `remove` are O(1).

Comment: What are the keys - strings, numbers, something else ...? How are they distributed? (e.g. a set of numbers from a limited range can have an efficient and compact representation)

Comment: @Joni, any explanation on the effect of the key types? Will effect the performance?

Comment: The key type affects the data structures that can be used and that in turn affects the performance.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). This will only have a single list of values, not a key-value pair like a `Map` has.

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

A quick search showed [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/simple-big-o-notation-post.html):

[image]

Comment: Note that `Set` uses a `Map` behind the scenes to achieve this. `HashSet` uses `HashMap`, `LinkedHashSet` uses `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeSet` uses `TreeMap`. So, from the question: *On one hand, I'd like to save memory by using key set only (like a Java List), on the other hand, I'd to run above 2 methods in O(1) time* it would be better using a `Map` instead.

Comment: It depends on his needs, I couldn't really figure out what it is he wants to do. If he has a key-value pair then he should take a `HashMap`, if it's just keys then he should take a `HashSet`.

Comment: This is already noted by [`Collections#newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LinkedHashSet` for this. If you need a simple interface, you come up with a new one:

```
interface SimpleSet{
    boolean containsKey(Object key);
    boolean remove(Object key);
}

class MySimpleSet extends LinkedHashSet implements SimpleSet{
    //... necessary contructors ...

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return contains(key);
    }
}
```

And declare it like this:

```
SimpleSet set = new MySimpleSet();
```

**Update on memory consumption**

`LinkedHashSet` takes ~40-50 bytes per stored element. So if it's too much, you could consider [`THashSet`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/set/hash/THashSet.html) or `TLinkedHashSet` from Trove4j which is ~4-8 bytes per element judging by this article: [Memory consumption of popular Java data types](http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/).